# str_replace() or htmlspecialchars() for escaping special characters in <pre> blocks

Tags: php, str-replace, htmlspecialchars

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and [should be represented by HTML entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) if they are to preserve their meanings.

That, with the limited knowledge that I have, can be easily done in two different ways in PHP. Like this:

```
<?php

   $some_code = '<a href="#test">Test</a>';

   echo '<pre><code>' . htmlspecialchars( $some_code, ENT_QUOTES ) . '</code></pre>';

?>
```

Or this way:

```
<?php

   $some_code = '<a href="#test">Test</a>';

   echo '<pre><code>' . str_replace( array('<', '>', '&', '\'', '"'), array('&lt;', '&gt;', '&amp;', '&apos;', '&quot;'), $some_code ) . '</code></pre>';

?>
```

(That's just to show you what I am trying to do, and not how I am doing it in reality. For example, the `$some_code` is provided dynamically, not manually.)

**Not considering** how much easier it is to simply use `htmlspecialchars()` over `str_replace()`, which one of the two would be a better choice for what I am trying to do? (In terms of performance, that is.)

---

### UPDATE

Okay, I see that this needs more context. This is what I am actually trying to do:

```
<?php

    $some_code = '<a href="#test">Test</a>';

    echo '<pre><code>' . str_replace(

        // Replace these special characters
        array( '<', '>', '&', '\'', '"', '‘', '’', '“', '”', '/', '[', ']' ),

        // With the HTML entities below, respectively
        array('&lt;', '&gt;', '&amp;', '&apos;', '&quot;', '&apos;', '&apos;', '&quot;', '&quot;', '&quot;', '&#47;', '&#91;', '&#93;'),

        $some_code

    ) . '</code></pre>';

?>
```

VERSUS:

```
<?php

    $some_code = '<a href="#test">Test</a>';

    return '<pre><code>' . str_replace(

        array( '‘', '’', '“', '”', '/', '[', ']' ),

        array('&apos;', '&apos;', '&quot;', '&quot;', '&quot;', '&#47;', '&#91;', '&#93;'),

        htmlspecialchars( $content, ENT_QUOTES )

    ) . '</code></pre>';

?>
```

Comment: This is what htmlspecialchars() are ment for, no need to complicate it by doing it different unless you are tayloring something special. If you suspect that you might change it in the future, make your own Html_Spes function with htmlspecialchars inside, so you only have to alter it in one place.

Comment: @Tom Please take a look at the update in my question. I actually need to replace more characters; guess I should have mentioned that initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `&` and `&amp;` to the start of each array to avoid double-escaping. After that, I’d suggest using just `str_replace`, since it makes what you’re trying to do more obvious (to me, anyways — nested function calls can be confusing!) but it’s really up to you. The performance difference won’t be noticeable; a string that big would cause other problems.

Comment: _"Your `str_replace` is going to double-escape `<` and `>`."_ I don't understand. Could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: @its_me: Passing an array to `str_replace` performs the replacements in order. `<` and `>` get turned into `&lt;` and `&gt;`, and then the next replacement turns those into `&amp;lt;` and `&amp;gt;`. http://codepad.viper-7.com/usA85U

Comment: In that case, what would the right way to do it? Also please take a look at the update in my question. It should give you more perspective on what I am actually trying to do. (+1)

Comment: @its_me: You would just make `&` and `&amp;` the first elements in the array. Also, is the difference between your two examples the fact that there are smart quotes? (i.e. `“` instead of `"`?) Why do you need to escape those?

Comment: @its_me: Anyways, in that case, pick either one. I’d go for `str_replace`, because it’s more clear that you want to replace a whole set of characters. The `htmlspecialchars` is easier to miss.

Comment: The difference is that I also need to escape smart quotes, forward slash and square brackets (required to work without issues in my application). As for escaping smart quotes, some code on the web has them instead of straight quotes. I want to auto-fix them without having to depend on my users.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should go with **htmlspecialchars()**. I made few benchmarks and got the result as for 100000 loops

```
htmlspecialchars took 0.15800881385803 to finish
htmlentities took 0.20201182365417 to finish
str_replace took 0.81704616546631 to finish
```

You can check it yourself by this code

```
<?php
$orgy = '<div style="background:#ffc">Hello World</div>';
$startTime = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++)
{
    $tmp = htmlspecialchars($orgy);
}
echo "htmlspecialchars took " . (microtime(true) - $startTime) . " to finish<br />";

$startTime = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++)
{
    $tmp = htmlentities($orgy);
}
echo "htmlentities took " . (microtime(true) - $startTime) . " to finish<br />";

$startTime = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++)
{
    $tmp = str_replace(array('&','<','>','\\','/','"','\''), array('&amp;','&lt;','&gt;','&#92;','&#47;','&quot;','&#039;'), $orgy);
}
echo "str_replace took " . (microtime(true) - $startTime) . " to finish\n";
?>
```